# Почему сбивается указатель и что он показывает?

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, указатели

Функция соединяет два интовых массива, при соединении больших массивов проблем не возникает, а при соединении маленьких все ломается.

```
int * merge_int(int * small,int * big,int lenth_s,int lenth_b){

 int result[lenth_b+lenth_s];
 int res_pointer = 0;

 printf("%s\n","massive for merge is:" );/*4*/
 print_massive(small,lenth_s);
 printf("%s\n","and : " );/*9*/
 print_massive(big,lenth_b);

 for (int i = 0; i < lenth_s; i++) {
   result[i]=small[i];
   res_pointer++;
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < lenth_b; i++) {
   result[res_pointer]=big[i];
   res_pointer++;
 }

 int *res = result;

 printf("%s\n","result is:" );
 print_massive(res,lenth_s+lenth_b);/*4,9*/

 return res;/*10,0*/
}
```

Comment: Вам уже несколько раз отвечали именно на этот вопрос. Причем всего три дня назад вы сами отмечали как "принятый" ответ, где детально описана суть проблемы. Вы целенаправленно занимаетесь подбрасыванием одинаковых вопросов для "накруток"? Или дело в чем-то другом?

Answer (score 0):

```
int result[lenth_b+lenth_s];
...
int *res = result;
...
return res;
```

Типичный возврат указателя на локальную переменную - источник сногих бед. На другие ошибки уже не смотрел....

**Update**

```
int * result = malloc(sizeof(int)*(lenth_b+lenth_s));
```

Только потом не забудьте `free()` вызвать.

Comment: А можете пояснить как правильно ?

Comment: См. добавление в ответе.

Comment: А что оно возвращало ? Так как это явно был не мусор в памяти.

Comment: @W i: И "как правильно" вам тоже подробно расписали в ответах на ваш же вопрос три дня назад.